# Typing attributes in a Sequelize Model class

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

Say I have Contact, which is a Sequelize model defined like this:

```js
class Contact extends Model<Contact> {
    id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;

    public static createContact = (options: Contact): Contact => new Contact(options);

    public getName = (): string => `${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`;
}
```

In the definition of `createContact` I have the *options* argument which should contain the attributes (i.e. *id*, *first_name*, *last_name*). Using `Contact` as the type works, but it's not quite correct because it should really only be the attributes.

I could define a separate type containing these attributes, but I would still have to write them within the class as well. **How can I avoid this redundancy, and define the attributes in only one place?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnlyAttrs<T>` to extract only attributes from a type:

```js
// extract props that are NOT functions
type OnlyAttrs<T> = {
  [K in {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown ? never : K;
  }[keyof T]]: T[K];
};

// then this type only includes attributes
type ContactAttrs = OnlyAttrs<Contact>;
```

then in the method:

```js
public static createContact = (options: ContactAttrs): Contact => new Contact(options);
```